# Devise + Omniauth = undefined method `new_session_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to implement a login system that only supports login through a Google Account to access Analytics data.

I cannot get it working with the exception

```
undefined method `new_session_path' for #<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController:0x8f588b0>
```

I'm using `omniauth` with the `omniauth-google-oauth2` strategy.

This is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'devise'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

This is the `config/routes.rb`

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_in', :to => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get 'sign_out', :to => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  root :to => "Landing#index"
end
```

`app/model/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  # :database_authenticatable, :registerable
  # :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  devise :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  # attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

`config/intitializers/omniauth.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'ID', 'SECRET', :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
end
```

`app/controllers/users/omniauth_callback_controller.rb`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
    # You need to implement the method below in your model
    @user = User.find_for_google_oauth2(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Can you please help me to understand what's wrong here?

P.S. this is the result I get running `rake routes`

```
user_omniauth_callback    /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)  users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:(?!))
new_user_session GET     /sign_in(.:format)                      users/sessions#new
destroy_user_session GET /sign_out(.:format)                     users/sessions#destroy
root                     /                                       Landing#index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of devise are you running? [This closed issue](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1390) seem to deal with the same problem, and assumes that it was gonna be fixed in version 1.4.9 and offers a quick and dirty fix.

But, if it doesn't help, try to change the named route for new session to:

```
get 'sign_in', :to => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_session
```

Also, I asked the question about Devise with Omniauth that you may find useful: [Devise omniauthable breaks Omniauth authentication with `Could not find a valid mapping for path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577089/devise-omniauthable-breaks-omniauth-authentication-with-could-not-find-a-valid)

Comment: I'm using Devise v2.1.0. Your suggested fix makes it work, but now I'm just getting: `uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController`. 

Do you have any idea about the reason?

Pff, it seemed so easy to integrate it :-s

Comment: Did you the fix they suggested in a closed ticket on Github? The one that defines `new_session_path` in `ApplicationController`? Did you try it? Or and did you overwrite default Devise Sessions controller?

Comment: I'm using Devise 2.1.1 so it shouldn't apply to me. I didn't overwrite the default session controller... maybe should I specify 'devise/sessions#new' instead of 'users/sessions#new'? I've tried creating the required class (simply inheriting from the devise one) and changing 'users/sessions#new' with 'devise/sessions#new' but I get a white page. I've currently removed the google_oauth2 method from the callback since it's not getting called :-/

Comment: I removed the omniauth initializer using the devise one (config.omniauth :google_oauth2) but the problem is still the same.

Comment: I opened a new question, to make it easier to find a solution for others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065439/cannot-getting-devise-omniauthable-working

Thanks.