# Cannot getting devise omniauthable working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I need to access google APIs, I'm trying to make users log in with their google account using Devise 2.1.1 and Omniauth (using the gem `google_oauth2` since OAuth2 is the reccomended one from google docs).

Unfortunatly I cannot get it working, this is the `routes.rb`

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'Landing#index'

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_in', :to => 'users/sessions#new', :as => :new_session
    get 'sign_out', :to => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_session
  end
end
```

Then I configured `config/initializers/devise.rb` to include a line with

```
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 'ID', 'SECRET', {access_type: 'offline', approval_prompt: 'force', scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'}
```

And actually I've a void callback class `app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
end
```

When I click on "Sign in with Google" I got redirected on Google, asking for authorization, then I go back to the callback, and I get redirected on the URL `http://localhost:3000/sign_in.user`with the error

```
uninitialized constant Users::SessionsController
```

What's wrong here? I spent 2 day trying to figure out it by myself, I played with a lot of configurations but never get it working, it's starting frustrating me.

This is the output from `rake routes`

```
root     /                                      Landing#index
user_omniauth_authorize     /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/google_oauth2/}
user_omniauth_callback     /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:google_oauth2)
new_session GET /sign_in(.:format)                     users/sessions#new
destroy_session GET /sign_out(.:format)                    users/sessions#destroy
```

Comment: why your callback controller is empty? You need `google_oauth2` action there.

Comment: It's empty because also implementing a `google_oauth2` nothing is happening, so I was thinking to leave it empty to see some sort of error... it seems to me that it doesn't get called at all. Also with the proper action it shows that error...

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're being redirected to your `sign_in` route which searches for `users/sessions#new` per your `routes.rb`.

However, `Users::SessionsController` does not exist resulting in the error you describe.

I'm not sure in which scenarios Devise/OmniAuth redirects you to that specific route, but I imagine you can either have it go to your homepage (where people can click the Google OAuth sign in button/link again) or connect it directly to the Google OAuth page. (This may get people stuck in an infinite loop depending on how Devise/OmniAuth uses the `sign_in` route.)