# omniauth callback could not find mapping devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin, omniauth

I have the following output for `rake routes`:

```
$ rake routes | grep linkedin
admin_user_linkedin_omniauth_authorize GET|POST   /auth/linkedin(.:format)                    users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 admin_user_linkedin_omniauth_callback GET|POST   /auth/linkedin/callback(.:format)           users/omniauth_callbacks#linkedin
      user_linkedin_omniauth_authorize GET|POST   /auth/linkedin(.:format)                    users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
       user_linkedin_omniauth_callback GET|POST   /auth/linkedin/callback(.:format)           users/omniauth_callbacks#linkedin
```

The file `app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` is:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def linkedin
    @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    puts(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
    else
      session["devise.linkedin_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      session[:user_id]
    end
  end
end
```

The devise initializer script has the following

```
config.omniauth_path_prefix = '/auth'
```

and the `config/routes.rb` file is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_config = ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_config[:controllers][:omniauth_callbacks] = 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
  # Based off the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30270909/1190388
  devise_for :admin_users, {class_name: 'User'}.merge(devise_config)
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'home#index'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {
               :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks'
             }
end
```

When I head to the `/auth/linkedin` page, I generate the correct callback and everything, however, I get the following runtime error:

> Could not find a valid mapping for path `"/auth/linkedin/callback"`
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> {"code"=>"SOME_HASH_1", "state"=>"ANOTHER_HASH_2"}
> ```

what could be the issue for the same?

PS: The closest similar question I could find was [Devise omniauthable breaks Omniauth authentication with `Could not find a valid mapping for path`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8577089/1190388) but it does not help in my case.

Comment: you can check this issue https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2004 .
It's very old but it may help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you fix this?